# Defering execution of a block of Perl code

Tags: perl

In `lib/MyModule.pm`:

```
package MyModule;
DEFER: {
    print "foo";
}
1;
```

In `script.pl`:

```
use MyModule;
print "bar";
```

I want to be able to output:

```
bar
foo
```

That is, I want to defer the execution of code inside the DEFER: block into the runtime and preferably after the code in the caller is executed. Sort of the opposite of BEGIN {}. Currently I use END {}, which is pretty much the opposite of BEGIN {} I suppose, but I wonder if there are other alternatives. One of the requirements is that the caller code only wants to do `use MyModule` and nothing additional.

Comment: It'll help to know what this is for, and what problems are you having with `END`.

Comment: How would `DEFER` differ from `END`?

Comment: If you want the block to executed at the end of the file's execution (i.e. at the end of the current lexical scope) rather than at the end of the program as with `END`, you can use something like Sub::ScopeFinalizer

Comment: A convenience shortcut module. `MyModule` will perform some setup as well as additional code to execute after the caller's code. Currently END works, but my concern is that this might interfere with other piece of code/module that uses END for something different.

Comment: There is no problem with having multiple END blocks.

Comment: Thanks, Sub::ScopeFinalizer might be handy.

Comment: An issue with `END` would be that the program has started "global destruction", deallocating memory, closing filehandles. In an `END` block you couldn't depend on the program being in a consistent state like you can during the regular run phase.

Comment: @mob I thought `END` happened just before global destruction.

Comment: @mob True, especially if `use MyModule` is called early resulting in its END block being called very late (since END execution follows LIFO order).

Comment: @mob But maybe that's an issue with DESTROY, and not END particularly?

Comment: Yeah, I think you guys are right about END-phase vs. global destruction phase.

Comment: In the END phase you are definitely in a different land as @mob says. Even if global destruction (in particular) didn't start, other things have changed; for example (at least some) signal handlers are gone (you can reinstall in the first-to-run END block).  But as for your concern voiced in a comment, END blocks are independent so it's not clear how this one would interfere with others.

Comment: A note just in case: as `END` blocks run in the order opposite of how they show in code this includes the `use` statements as well.  So `END` from this module runs after `END` in the caller (assuming caller's `END` comes after `use` statements) or `END` in packages which `use` statements come after it in the caller, but before `END` in packages with `use` statements before it in the caller.

Comment: See [`Manip::END`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Manip::END) for some help with controlling the order that END blocks run in.